# jqGrid > datatype : "local" > get and save (at once) all edited cells of a column?

Tags: jqgrid

I have a grid with a `datatype = "local"`. The data are an array as follows:

```
var mydata = [{id:1,valeur:"a_value",designation:"a_designation"}, {id:2,...}, ...];
```

The second column (named **valeur**) is the only editable column of the grid (`editable:true` set in `colModel`)

In the pager of the grid, I have 2 buttons:

- One to edit all cells (at once) of the column named **valeur**:

  ```
  $("#mygrid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pager',{caption:"Edit values",
  onClickButton:function(){ var ids = $('#mygrid').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
  for(var i=0;i<ids.length+1;i++){ $('#mygrid').jqGrid('editRow',ids[i],true);}
  }});
  ```
- and another one to save (at once) all the changes of the edited cells:

  ```
  $("#mygrid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pager',{caption:"Save changes",
  onClickButton:function(){var ids = $('#mygrid').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
  for(var i=0;i<ids.length+1;i++){ 
     ... ??? ...
  }}});
  ```

When I use:

```
var rd = $("#mygrid").jqGrid('getRowData',ids[i]);
alert("valeur="+rd.valeur);
```

for each display, I get something like this:

```
valeur=< input class="editable" role="textbox" name="valeur" id="1_valeur" style="width: 98%;" type="text"> ...
```

- So, when cells are in edition mode, all **rd.valeur** are an input text tag!
- When they are not, I get the initial values of the cells!

How can I get and save all changes of this column (all cells in edition mode)?

Comment: ...the best would be to save the changes first in the array then to the server

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `getRowData` is not intended for use while a row is in edit mode. From the [jqGrid Docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods):

> Do not use this method when you editing the row or cell. This will return the cell content and not the actuall value of the input element

As you observed, if you attempt to use this method when a row is being edited, you will get raw HTML instead of the value. You have two options here:

- As Qualliarys suggests, you could save the data first, for example using `saveRow`.
- Alternatively, you can parse the input tags yourself, perhaps using jQuery to assist.

Comment: Thank you Justin for your response! 

In fact, i tried to use saveRow and saveCell but without success. I have got an error something like that : "error row: 1 result: 404:not found status: error". 

For the alternative you suggest... it was my first thought. So if it's the only solution i will do so!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to solve my problem. I tried with any id and it works well, the change is saved:

```
...
onSelectRow: function(id){
  $('#list4').jqGrid('saveRow',lastsel,false,'clientArray');
  if(id && id!==lastsel){
    $('#list4').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
    lastsel=id;
  }
  $('#list4').jqGrid('editRow',id,false);
},
...
```

url (fourth param): if defined, this parameter replaces the `editurl` parameter from the options array. If set to `'clientArray'`, the data is not posted to the server but rather is saved only to the grid (presumably for later manual saving). reference: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow

In fact, I tried this way, but I wrote `'mydata'` instead of `'clientArray'`...

So thank you so much Oleg and Justin, we got it!

Answer (score 1):

You try to use jqGrid with his own way. Why? Switching of all rows of jqGrid at the same time in edit mode I find not as the best way.

If you really need to make the most operation with the grid locally and send the results at the end you can try the new beta version of jqGrid. It can be probably the best way for you. See http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/releases/jqgrid-3-7-beta/#p17463 for details.

Comment: Oleg, thank you for your response and for the link.

Yes it's not the best way to use jqGrid. But for this grid, it's better for me to display the data vertically (the data displayed are in fact a single row of a SQL table). This single row contains a lot of elements. If i display it horizontally (as default) the grid will be too large and its height will be very small... i hope you understand my problem ?

Comment: OK, I understand that the data should be displayed vertically, but it is not clear for me why you want change the whole first column in edit mode. I standard way that if user select a row or make double-click on a row the selected row will be changed in edit mode. After the user press "enter" key the data will be saved and the edit mode will be switch off. If the user press "esc" key or goes to the next row without pressing of "enter" key, the changes will not be saved. Why this way is not suitable for you?

Comment: Oleg, that is suitable for my too !!! In fact i started to search a solution this way, with: ...
onSelectRow: function(id){
        $('#mygrid').jqGrid('saveCell',lastsel+"_valeur","valeur","mydata");

    if(id && id!==lastsel){
      $('#mygrid').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
      lastsel=id;
    }
      $('#mygrid').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
  } ... but i got the same error mentionned above.

Comment: It can be important which version of jqGrid you use. Download the last uncompressed version from http://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid. If you do prefer a compressed version from http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6 then don't forget select all modules which you need before clicking of download key. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863874/jqgrid-edit-only-certain-rows-for-an-editable-column/2866685#2866685 for an example of line editing. It must work.

Comment: Oleg, i did twince you mentionned ... but when i press "enter" i get the same error. Here is my code : ...
ondblClickRow: function(id, ri, ci) { $('#mygrid').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);},
onSelectRow: function(id){    
    if(id && id!==lastsel){
      $('#mygrid').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
      lastsel=id;
    }
  },...

Comment: Could you insert in your question a full code. If I could reproduce your problem I could better help you. One more question is stay unanswer: which version of jqGrid and jQuery you use?

Comment: i use jquery.jqGrid-3.6.5/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js .... you will find my code test in a new answer :

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ( document).ready(function(){
var lastsel=-1;
$("#list4").jqGrid({
  data:mydata,
  datatype: "local",
  pager: '#pager14',
  height:"100%",
  autowidth: true,
  multiselect: false,
  sortable:false,
  sortname: 'id',
  sortorder: "desc",
  colNames:['Index','Label','Value','Designation','','Name'],
  colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id',sorttype:"int",hidden:true},    
    {name:'label',index:'label',sorttype:"text",resizable:false,width:80},
    {name:'valeur',editable:true,resizable:false,width:85},
    {name:'designation',index:'designation',sorttype:"text",resizable:false,width:200},
    {name:'unite',sortable:false,align:'center',resizable:false,width:10},
    {name:'name',index:'name',sorttype:"text",hidden:true}
  ],  
  afterInsertRow: function(rowid){    
    $("#list4").jqGrid('setCell',rowid,'label','',{'font-weight':'bold','border-top':'0px','border-left':'0px'});
    $("#list4").jqGrid('setCell',rowid,'label','','ui-state-default');
  },
  ondblClickRow: function(id, ri, ci) {
    $('#list4').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
  },
  onSelectRow: function(id){
    if(id && id!==lastsel){
      $('#list4').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
      lastsel=id;
    }
  },
  footerrow :false,
  pgbuttons:true,
  editurl: "client_test2.php",
  caption: "Event identity : attention il faut mettre un certificat en S_SESSION !!!"
});

var mydata = [
  {id:1,label:"Buyer",valeur:"<?php echo $_SESSION["certificats"][0]["acheteur"]?>",designation:"Nom de l'acheteur de la marchandise",unite:"",name:'acheteur'},
  {id:2,label:"Contract",valeur:"<?php echo $_SESSION["certificats"][0]["contrat"]?>",designation:"Liste des contrats établis entre les vendeurs et l'acheteur",unite:"",name:'contrat'},
  {id:3,label:"Seller",valeur:"<?php echo $_SESSION["certificats"][0]["vendeur"]?>",designation:"Nom du vendeur de la marchandise",unite:"",name:'vendeur'},
  {id:4,label:"Network",valeur:"<?php echo $_SESSION["certificats"][0]["filiere"]?>",designation:"Filière complète des vendeurs",unite:"",name:'filiere'},
  {id:5,label:"Product",valeur:"<?php echo $_SESSION["certificats"][0]["produit"]?>",designation:"Nom de la marchandise",unite:"",name:'produit'},
  {id:6,label:"Variety",valeur:"<?php echo $_SESSION["certificats"][0]["variete"]?>",designation:"Nom de la variété de la marchandise",unite:"",name:'variete'},
  {id:7,label:"Weight",valeur:"<?php echo $_SESSION["certificats"][0]["poids"]?>",designation:"Nombre de tonnes contracté",unite:"<img src=\'/img/v3/aide0.png\'title=\'Metric Ton : 1000,000 mt\'/>",name:'poids'},
  {id:8,label:"Controler",valeur:"<?php echo $_SESSION["certificats"][0]["controleur"]?>",designation:"Identitées du contrôleur",unite:"",name:'controleur'},
  {id:9,label:"Start",valeur:"<?php echo $_SESSION["certificats"][0]["debut"]?>",designation:"Date et heure de début de l'événement",unite:"<img src=\'/img/v3/aide0.png\'title=\'Datetime : 2008-02-23 08:00:00\'/>",name:'debut'},
  {id:10,label:"End",valeur:"<?php echo $_SESSION["certificats"][0]["fin"]?>",designation:"Date et heure de fin de l'événement",unite:"<img src=\'/img/v3/aide0.png\'title=\'Datetime : 2008-02-23 08:00:00\'/>",name:'fin'},
];

for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++){
  $("#list4").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);
}

$("#list4").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager14",{view:false,edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:false,refreshtext:''});
$("#list4").jqGrid('sortableRows');

$("#list4").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pager14',{
  caption:"Edit values &nbsp;",buttonicon:"ui-icon-pencil",
  onClickButton:function(){
    var ids = $('#list4').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for(var i=0;i<ids.length+1;i++){
      $('#list4').jqGrid('editRow',ids[i],true);
    }
  }
});


$("#list4").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pager14',{
  caption:"Save changes &nbsp;",buttonicon:"ui-icon-disk",
  onClickButton:function(){
    var ids = $('#list4').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for(var i=0;i<ids.length+1;i++){
      $('#list4').jqGrid('saveRow',ids[i],false,'mydata');
    }
  }
});

$("#list4").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pager14',{
  caption:"",buttonicon:"ui-icon-info",
  onClickButton:function(){

  }
});


$("#list4 tr").hover(
  function(){$(this).find("td").eq(1).removeClass('ui-state-default'); $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");},
  function(){ if(!$(this).hasClass("ui-state-active")) $(this).find("td").eq(1).addClass('ui-state-default'); }
);

$("#list4 tr").click(
    function(){$("#list4 tr").each(function() {$(this).find("td").eq(1).addClass('ui-state-default'); });
    $(".ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");
    $(".ui-state-highlight").removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
    $(this).find("td").eq(1).removeClass('ui-state-default');
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-active");
});
});
```

Comment: the php file "client_test2.php" is empty for now!

Comment: By the way. The error message which you describe come from `editurl: "client_test2.php"`. Another part of code where you initialize `mydata` has syntax errors: `valeur:"<?php echo $_SESSION["certificats"][0]["acheteur"]?>"` is wrong. I don't understand how the code should looks like, but you should use either  `valeur:'<?php echo $_SESSION["certificats"][0]["acheteur"]?>'` or `valeur:"<?php echo $_SESSION[\"certificats\"][0][\"acheteur\"]?>"`. One more remark: It seems you could use `classes` parameter in the colModel (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options).

Comment: thank you Oleg. Yes, it comes from "client_test2.php", but when i comment this line and press the "enter" key, the grid becomes froze... but what shape it should have (it is write in last section of http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid37/jqgrid.html, that this url is a dummy existing url) ?

Comment: i tried to replace all '<?php ... ?>' with '' (with a empty string), but i got the same problem. In fact i would like to save the change before in mydata array...