# jqGrid: replace single click with double click to enter cell edit mode

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Using [cell edit mode in jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing), the default behaviour is to enter edit mode on a cell whenever that cell is clicked  or if that cell is selected and the enter key is pressed.

Is there a way to change this behaviour so that a single click does not place it in edit mode but a double click does? Entering into edit mode on enter is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly it is not supported by the cell editing mode, but it seems to me, that you can implement it yourself in the same way as for inline editing (see [jqGrid - edit only certain rows for an editable column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863874/jqgrid-edit-only-certain-rows-for-an-editable-column/2866685#2866685), for example). You should don't set `cellEdit` parameter of jqGrid to `true`, but use directly cell editing methods like `editCell` described in  http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#methods.

Another way is to use inline editing on double-click instead of cell editing.

Comment: Hi @Oleg, If I set cellEdit: false, then those cell editing methods like editCell don't work. So if one wants cell editing, but enabled on double-click (instead of row editing), then I guess it does not seem to be possible.

Comment: @rsmoorthy: You are right. The usage of double-click for the cell editing is not so easy. Either one have to write much more code or just use inline editing instead of the cell editing.

Answer (score 0):

First let me thank you in reading your responses I was able to come up with this solution.  I needed some specific behavior for cell editing. I needed to be able to select only a single row with a click. No multi select. I needed cell editing that was activated upon a double click. I needed to be able to  cancel an edit if a row other than the one selected was clicked. I also needed to be able to restrict user input. My initial google searches brought me here, and I had just about given up hope when I stumbled across other items you had posted.

Here is the solution that I came up with. Most of it was from your previous answers.  I made some changes. So most of this credit goes to you but I wanted to post it here to help others.  This is my first time posting a solution so I hope it is clear and helps.

edit.iCol. edit.iRow and edit.rowID are stored so that we can do a cancel on the edit.  User your own variables here to store these values.

```
        cellEdit: true,
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
        beforeSelectRow: function(rowid) {
           if (edit.iRow != null && rowid !== edit.rowID) {
               $('#list').jqGrid("restoreCell",edit.iRow, edit.iCol);
               edit.iRow = edit.iCol = null;
             }
           $('#list').jqGrid('setSelection', rowid); 
        },

        afterSaveCell: function (rowid, name, val, iRow, iCol) {        
              alert("after");
        },
        beforeSaveCell: function (rowid, name, val, iRow, iCol) {
             alert("before");
        },
        ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow,iCol) {
            edit.iRow = iRow; 
            edit.iCol = iCol; 
            edit.rowID = rowid;
            $("#list").editCell(iRow, iCol, true);
        }
```