# How to display the success messages in the Add,Edit and Delete dialog boxes in the JQGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Hi Am using JQGrid in my application,I want to show success messages or errors on the dialog boxes after inserting/updating/deleting in the database.Can any one help on these.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is depend on the [editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#editing) which you use. Because you wrote about inserting and deleting the data I suppose you use the [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing). In the case you can use `afterSubmit` or `afterComplete` [events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) to display additional information for the user after the saving of the data on the server. The `errorTextFormat` event is practical to displaying detailed error message generated by the server. The exact usage of the events depand on how you use [editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#editing). You can use `editGridRow` inside of `ondblClickRow` event handler for example (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982635/in-jqgrid-can-you-double-click-a-row-to-bring-up-the-edit-form/4983690#4983690)). In the case you should place the event handler in the list of `editGridRow` parameters which you use. If you use navigator buttons instead (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator)) then you can define additional options of `editGridRow` and `delGridRow` functions as the `prmEdit, prmAdd, prmDel` parameters of the [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition). I hope you understand what I mean.