# jQuery jqGrid Show message when an edit row is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, data-manipulation

I am following this tutorial here http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html in
LiveDataManipulation->EditRow

My grid receive data from script `a.php`. After the user can modify this data by the jqGrid.
jqGrid after the modification data will send data to script `B.php` that update my database and return a message of response like "all goes well".
I want that this response is alerted or showed to user somewhere on the page.
Reading the tutorial and here http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing I think that I've to use `afterSubmit` option, but I haven't understood how print on the edit panel the result.

I have written:

```
$("#editImpresa").click(function(){
var gr = jQuery("#tabImprese").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
if( gr != null ) jQuery("#tabImprese").jqGrid('editGridRow',gr,{
    height:690,
    width:500,
    closeAfterEdit : true,
    reloadAfterSubmit:false,
    afterSubmit: function(response,postdata){ 
       if(response.responseText=="ok")
            success=true;
        else success = false;

        return [success,response.responseText] 
    }
});
```

How can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: I want show the message result in the jqgrid panel where I can edit a row.

Comment: What you mean under "jqgrid panel"?

Comment: here in this panel: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/832/immaginae.png/

Comment: Do you mean the [edit form](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing)? Do you want to form will be not closed and you show an text message somewhere in the form dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all the option `closeAfterEdit:true` follows to closing of the edit form after the successful server response. You should change the setting to the default value `closeAfterEdit:false` to be able to show anything.

Next I would recommend you to use [navigator](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator) toolbar instead of creating a button after outside of the grid. In the case you can use

```
var grid = jQuery("#tabImprese");
grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#pager', {add:false,del:false,search:false}, prmEdit);
```

One more good option is to use `ondblClickRow` event handler

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
    $(this).jqGrid('editGridRow',rowid,prmEdit);
}
```

(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982635/in-jqgrid-can-you-double-click-a-row-to-bring-up-the-edit-form/4983690#4983690)) or both ways at the same time.

In any way you have to define the options of [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow) method (the `prmEdit`). It's important to know that [afterSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) will be called only if the server response not contains [error HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4). So you should use [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) to decode the error server response. The [afterSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) event handler you can use to display status message.

In the demo I used only `errorTextFormat` to demonstrate both displaying of the status and error message:

[image]

The status message goes away in 3 seconds:

[image]

The corresponding demo you will find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithMsgInEditForm.htm).

In real example you will of cause place the code writing status message inside of [afterSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) event handler and the code which returns the error message inside of [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events).

Comment: This solution does not show message if top of edit form is not visible. To reproduce in demo, resize edit window height to small, scrol down and press submit. Messages do not appear: they are rendered in top of edit form which is not visible. How to show messages always ?