# JQGrid: How can I display a custom message from server during an edit?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, jqgrid

In my application, when I edit an entry from jqgrid, I need to show some server messages in the edit form (like this email was already entered etc)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct you want to display custom error message or status message after submitting of the edit form. In the case it's most important to use correct HTTP status code which you can set by [HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx) for example. If you want return an error the server response should contain some error HTTP code. In the case the [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) callback can be used to format the message. If you want use display status message after successful modification you can use `afterComplete` callback instead.

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791463/jquery-jqgrid-show-message-when-an-edit-row-is-complete/6803206#6803206) you will find [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithMsgInEditForm.htm) which demonstrate how you can place successful status message in the form. The demo simulate successful message instead of usage `afterComplete` callback, but I hope you understand the idea how it can be done.

Comment: actually I made it work with 'editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: myFunc}', thanks a lot for response

Comment: @JeffNorman: You are welcome! The `editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: myFunc}` help you to implement *client side* validation, but `errorTextFormat` is very helpful for the server side validation. I use `errorTextFormat` in all forms of jqGrid which I made for my customers.

Answer (score 0):

try some model popup options like jquery UI dialog / jQmodel/Fancybox etc. But these all are client side plugins, If you are updating your grid value from client side java script ( via ajax), then u can use this.