# not able to get the actual record id

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I  have create the the jqgrid which loads the data from the server , i am able to view the data in a grid , but when i try to extend and fire up `onclickSubmit` of `$.jgrid.del` i am not be able to get the actual record id (which is in my case it is 101 , 102 ) instead of that it returns 1 , 2 , may be a row index id.

**JqGrid**

```
jQuery("#eventGrid").jqGrid({
    url:"/eventAllInfo",
    datatype: "json",
    restful:  true,
    mtype: 'GET',
    width:900,

    colNames:['id','title', 'description'],
    colModel:[ 
        {name:'e_info_id',index:'e_info_id', width:60, sorttype:"int",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
        {name:'e_meta_title',index:'e_meta_title', width:90,editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
        {name:'e_meta_description',index:'e_meta_description', width:100,editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},          
    ],
    rowNum:10, rowList:[10,20,30], 
    jsonReader : { repeatitems: false },
    pager: '#pager',        
    caption: "Show Events"
});
```

**JSON Response**

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Records Retrieved Successfully -EventAllInfo",
  "page": "1",
  "total": 1,
  "records": "2",
  "rows": [
    {
      "e_info_id": "101",
      "e_meta_title": "Oracle Business Summit",
      "e_meta_description": null,
      "e_meta_img": null,
      "e_meta_video": null,

    },
    {
      "e_info_id": "102",
      "e_meta_title": "Expo 2014 - Environment",
      "e_meta_description": "",
      "e_meta_img": "",
      "e_meta_video": "",

    }
  ]
}
```

Well specifying id in json reader solved my problem in deleting record , but when i edit the record my postdata argument contains

```
e_info_id: "101"
e_meta_description: ""
e_meta_title: "Oracle Business Summit"
id: "101"
oper: "edit"
```

and when i try to access it as postdata.id or postdata.e_info_id it returns undefined , here is the onclickSubmit of edit

```
 onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata) {
        console.log(postdata);
        console.log(postdata.id); //undefined


        options.url = options.editurl +'/' + encodeURIComponent(postdata.id);
    }
```

Comment: About `onclickSubmit`: Please read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9923417/315935) on your previous question carefully. The property of `postdata` which hold the `id` has *not* the name `id`. It will be `eventGrid_id` in your case. The property name are constructed from the `id` of the grid and `"_id"` text: `gridId + "_id"`.

Comment: If you would add "jquery" or "javascript" tag to the question the code will be marked in JavaScript specific colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }` jqGrid don't know which values it should use as so named rowid. The rowid is the value of `id` attribute of `<tr>` elements in the grid.

To fix the problem you have two options:

1. To define `key: true` property in the `e_info_id` column.
2. To use `id: "e_info_id"` in `jsonReader` (see the answer of Christian)

The default value of `id` property in the `jsonReader` is `id: "id"`.

It's important to know that the `id` value have to be **unique** on the page. If you for example have two grids on the page and both have information with integer ids you can have conflicts. In the case you can use `idPrefix` option. In the case the value of `id` attribute of `<tr>` elements will be constructed from the `idPrefix` (which should be different in both pages of cause) and the "standard" `id`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the docs [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data) I think you should specify your id property name in the jsonReader.

```
jsonReader : { repeatitems: false, id: "e_info_id" }
```

Comment: +1 from me. Your answer is absolutely correct. I just added additional information in my answer.

Comment: @Hunt: You should vote up such answers too if you want to receive answers on your questions in the future. You can read in [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) very simple rule: "**As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer**". Typically one should vote up all answers on your own which was in any way helpful. Voting answers on other questions help other visitors of the same page.