# jqgrid how to show server side messages

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, jqgrid, response

I am using `jqGrid` to show data in tabular format, using `JSP` and `servlet`.

**EDIT**

I want to show errors from server, when operations like `insert, update, delete` are performed. `(datatype: "xml")`

**JQGrid**

```
jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid({
                height:250,
                width:600,
                url:'Assignment?action=Assign',
                datatype: "xml",
                colNames:['Sr. No.','PID',  'DATE',  'EMPID'],
                colModel:[{name:'srNo',index:'srNo', width:30,sortable:false},
                           {name:'PID',index:'PID',width:0, sortable:true,editable:false},
                           {name:'DATE',index:'DATE', width:75,sortable:true,editable:true,editoptions: { dataInit: function(el) { setTimeout(function() { $(el).datepicker({dateFormat:"dd-M-yy",showButtonPanel: true,changeYear: true,changeMonth: true}).attr('readonly','readonly'); }, 200); }}},
                           {name:'EMPID',index:'EMPID', width:150,sortable:true,editable:true}
                           ],
                rowNum:10,
                rowList:[10,20,50,100],
                pager: '#pager10_d',
                sortname: 'PID',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "asc",

                    },
                multiselect: true,
                editurl: "Assignment?action=Edit",
                caption:"Assignment"
            } ).navGrid('#pager10_d',{edit:false,add:true,del:false,addtext:'Assign '},
                    {},
                    {modal:true,jqModal: false,closeOnEscape:true,savekey: [true,13],closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true,width:500,mtype:'POST', url: 'Assignment',editData:{action: 'Assign',PID: function () {return PID;}}, 
                afterSubmit: function (response) {
                        alert('After Submit \n' +'statusText: '+ response.statusText);
                        var myInfo = '<div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all">'+
                                     '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" ' +
                                         'style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>' +
                                     response.statusText + 'Inserted'+
                                     '</div>',
                             $infoTr = $("#TblGrid_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + ">tbody>tr.tinfo"),
                            $infoTd = $infoTr.children("td.topinfo"); 
                        $infoTd.html(myInfo);
                        $infoTr.show();

                        // display status message to 3 sec only
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $infoTr.slideUp("slow");
                        }, 5000);

                        return [true, "", ""]; // response should be interpreted as successful
                    },
                    errorTextFormat: function (response) {
                    alert('Error Text Format: \n' +'statusText: '+ response.statusText);

                        return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" ' +
                                     'style="float:left; margin-right:.3em;"></span>' +
                                    response.statusText;},
                    {closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true,mtype: 'POST',url: 'Assignment',delData: {action: 'Delete',PID: function () {return PID;}}},
                    {}) ;
```

**Servlet Code**

```
if(request.getParameter("action").equalsIgnoreCase("Assign"))
        {
            PID = request.getParameter("PID");
            String DATE= request.getParameter("DATE");
            String EMPID= request.getParameter("EMPID");

            String query = "insert into ASSIGN(PID,DATE,EMPID) values('"+ PID +"','"+ DATE +"','"+ EMPID"')";
            boolean b = insert.InsertData(query);
            if(b)
            {
                System.out.println("New record added successfully! : "+query);
                response.setContentType("text/xml");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

                //response.sendError(200, "success");
                response.setStatus(200, "Inserted successfully");

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Failed to add Record! : "+query);
                response.setContentType("text/xml");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

                //response.sendError(399, "not Inserted successfully");   
                response.setStatus(404, "Error while inserting");   
            }           
        }//INSERT
```

for above example

- after `inserting` record from jqgrid, then `No message is shown` in
  grid if record is `inserted successfully`
- `error Status: 'Unauthorized'. Error code: 401` is shown if servlet fails to insert record in database.

My Question is that:

- after `inserting` record from jqgrid, if the record is inserted then how should i show message giving information to user that data is inserted.
- and how should I give message to user that `Error while inserting` (which `error code` should i use for this?)

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggested in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6803206/315935) and in [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13912926/315935) to use existing hidden row of grid form (`tr.tinfo`) to display information which is not error. Because the answers are not well known I repeat the same information here, but I'll try to explain all more detailed.

First of all it's important to understand which elements has the standard Edit/Add form. Using Developer Tools of IE or Chrome, Firebug or many other tool one can easy find out that the Add/Edit form created by jqGrid contains **two hidden rows on top of the form**:

[image]

The first row will be used per default as the place for error message. One can use `errorTextFormat` to customize the information a little.

If the server response contains error HTTP status code (>=400) then the callback `errorTextFormat` will be called and you can use

```js
errorTextFormat: function (response) {
    return response.responseText;
}
```

or something like

```js
errorTextFormat: function (response) {
    return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" ' +
                 'style="float:left; margin-right:.3em;"></span>' +
                response.responseText;
}
```

to display error message like

[image]

In the same way one can use `afterSubmit` callback to display status message after submitting of edited/added data if the server response contains successful [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). The implementation of `afterSubmit` could be about the following

```
afterSubmit: function (response) {
    var myInfo = '<div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all">'+
                 '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" ' +
                     'style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>' +
                 response.responseText +
                 '</div>',
        $infoTr = $("#TblGrid_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + ">tbody>tr.tinfo"),
        $infoTd = $infoTr.children("td.topinfo");
    $infoTd.html(myInfo);
    $infoTr.show();

    // display status message to 3 sec only
    setTimeout(function () {
        $infoTr.slideUp("slow");
    }, 3000);

    return [true, "", ""]; // response should be interpreted as successful
}
```

The code will display the status message for 3 sec only abd then uses [jQuery.slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) animation to hide it. It will look like

[image]

I hope it's what you need.

Comment: i have updated my question, after implementing your code, now messages are shown on top of the form as you shown in image, but only status code are shown, like when inserted successfully only `OK` is shown, and when failed to insert then only `Not Found` is shown, but i am not able to show `custom` message sent by servlet in form.. am i doing mistake while sending error from servlet to grid? any help will be appreciated...

Comment: @Bhushan: Probably you used [response.statusText](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-statustext-attribute) instread of [response.responseText](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-responsetext-attribute). Could you compare the current code of my answer with youth one?

Comment: i have used `response.responseText`, but it displays nothing

Comment: @Bhushan: You should verify the information from HTTP response from the server. You Fiddler, Firebug or Developer Tools of IE (press F12 to start) or Google Chrome to examine full HTTP traffic. You can additionally set breakpoint inside of `afterSubmit` and examine properties of `response`

Comment: @Bhushan: Do you fixed your server code? I'm not Java developer, but I suppose that the usage of second parameter of `response.setStatus` (like `response.setStatus(200, "Inserted successfully");`)  is the wrong way. The code like `PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); out.print("Inserted successfully"); out.flush();` seems me more correct. Probably you should use `response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");` instead of `response.setContentType("text/xml")`. See [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.servlet.http/HttpServletResponsesetContentTypetexthtmlcharsetUTF8.htm).

Comment: sorry for late reply, yes i think you are right. today i am going to fix that issue, so i will let you know what was the mistake...

Comment: @Bhushan: I seen accidentally that you modified your question. Please write should comment to notify about it. You current code still use `response.statusText` and `response.setContentType("text/xml")`. If you use `response.setContentType("text/xml")` you should return correct XML data in the response. In the case you could require to use `response.responseXML` to access to the response. So I recommended previously use `text/html` as `Content-Type` and place the status message directly in the body of the response. In the case you'll can access it per `response.responseText`

Comment: @Bhushan: I think that all your current problems are not jqGrid related. You should just place the status message in the server response. Depend on how you do this you can access the information inside of `afterSubmit` or `errorTextFormat`.

Comment: Thanks for you help Oleg. I think you have done PHD or something similar in JQGRID....

Answer (score 3):

I have done somthing similar on an edit call to my server so I think this would work in a very similar manner to an add.

On the controller after an edit/delete/add call you would determine if there is a message to be passed to the user and if so pass it via the JSON (XML in your case) back to the grid.

Ex

```
    if (infoDialogTrigger) { 
       return Json(new { success = true, showMessage = true, message = "Updating your Inventory and we are displaying this info box" }); 
    }//if
    else { 
       return Json(new { success = true, showMessage = false, message = "" }); 
    }//else
```

In your jqGrid you would have your edit/delete/add function:

```
    function EditCollectionItem (rowid, grid){
        $(grid).jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid,
        {
            viewPagerButtons: false,
            editData: { },
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                var DialogVars = $.parseJSON(response.responseText); //parse the string that was returned in responseText into an object
                //if there was a failure with the update, or there was information to pass to the user
                if (!DialogVars.success || DialogVars.showMessage) {
                    alert(DialogVars.message);
                }
            } //afterComplete
        }); //$(grid).jqGrid('editGridRow
    }//function EditCollectionItem (rowid, grid){
```

So in the above example if the operation was a failure you could show a message with a `success = false` or if the operation was completed but you wanted to pass some extra information to the user you could as well with `sucess = true` && `showMessage = true`.

This is a JSON example of an edit but the concepts and logic should be the same for XML and an add/delete operation.