# jqGrid: displaying server error message

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid edit form that contains a date field. I want to implement exception handling so that error messages from the server will be displayed in the edit form. Example response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Date: Fri, 28 Jun 2013 15:47:21 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close

11
"Bad Date format"
0
```

jqGrid only displays "error status:'Bad Request' Error Code: 400", at the top of the form. How can I have it also display the error message: "Bad Date format" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) callback of form editing. As the parameter the callback get [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object which is wrapper on [XMLHTTPRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) object. It's [responseText](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-responsetext-attribute) property represent the body of the response (`11\n"Bad Date format"\n0` in your case). The [status](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-status-attribute) property gets you the HTTP status code (`400` in your example). You can use [getResponseHeader](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getresponseheader%28%29-method) and [getAllResponseHeaders](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getallresponseheaders%28%29-method) to examine all [HTTP headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

By the way I find very strange that the response contains `Content-Type: application/json`, but the body of the response don't contains JSON string.

Comment: Oleg, thank you for your response. I followed your instructions and was able to read the message error this way: {mtype:"POST", addCaption:"Add New System Message",
     errorTextFormat: function(request) {
     var message = request.responseText;
     alert(message);
    }}, ... Now how do I get the messag to actually display automatically at the top of the form, if possible appended to the rest of the error message?

Comment: BTW the content-type is the originally declared mime-type, as returned by CXF. It doesn't update it in case of error apparently.

Comment: @Pablo: `errorTextFormat` callback should return string with the text or HTML fragment which should be displayed. You can find an example in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6803206/315935). See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithMsgInEditForm.htm) from the answer. Be carefull, the part of the code of `errorTextFormat` in the demo is **dummy code** which should be removed.

Comment: Got it Oleg. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your response contains 2 fields: status (OK, ERROR,..) and message then you should write a function like this:

```
    validateAfterSubmit = function(response, postdata){
        var json   = response.responseText; // response text is returned from server.
        var result = JSON.parse(json); // convert json object into javascript object.
        return [result.status == 'OK', result.message, null];
    };
```

and specify in the edit/add options:

```
            //edit options
            { url: '...',
                afterSubmit: validateAfterSubmit
            },
            //add options
            { url: '...',
                afterSubmit: validateAfterSubmit
            },
```

hopefully this can help